# How to get the cell.textLabel.text from the selected cell in DetailViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview, viewcontroller

I've got a UITableView with several entrys, and these are divided up in several sections. If I click on one of the cells, a DetailViewController is accessed. In that DetailViewController, I want to use the data from the selected cell (the cell.textLabel and the cell.detailTextLabel), but I can't access these.
Is there a possibility to solve the problem so I can access the textLabels from the selected cells with the DetailViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add properties to DetailViewController for the two text values.  Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //create your DetailViewController here
    UIViewController *detailViewController = ...

    //set the properties...        
    detailViewController.cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    detailViewController.cellDetailText = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

    //push the detailViewController here

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `DetailViewController` with the cell content.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithText:cell.textLabel.text] autorelease];
    // push
}
```

Instead of the child reading from it's parent, It far cleaner to have the parent provide the info directly to it's child.